# Помогите исправить ошибку: «sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.»

Tags: python, sqlite

#### Ошибка:

> self.cursor.execute('UPDATE tmp set page =? WHERE user_id =?',
>   (data,)) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings
>   supplied. The current  statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

#### Код:

```
...
def save_page(self, user_id, page):
    with self.connection:
        sql = ('INSERT INTO tmp(user_id, page) VALUES(:user_id,:page)')
        data = {}
        data["user_id"] = user_id
        data['page'] = page
        self.cursor.execute(sql, data)

        data = {}
        data["user_id"] = user_id
        data['page'] = page + 1
        self.cursor.execute('UPDATE tmp set page =? WHERE user_id =?', (data,))
    pass
...
```

#### Таблица:

```
`CREATE TABLE tmp (user_id integer, page integer, UNIQUE (user_id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании неименованных аргументов, необходимо передавать кортеж с нужным количеством аргументов

```
self.cursor.execute('UPDATE tmp set page =? WHERE user_id =?', (data['page'], data['user_id']))
```

либо, если передаёте словарь, используйте именованные аргументы

```
self.cursor.execute('UPDATE tmp set page =:page WHERE user_id =:user_id', data)
```